# How to move a widget below the menu in a sidebar in twenty thirteen?

Tags: customization

I am Jack - a new member.
I am relatively new to the WP.  I can use HTML and CSS pretty well and use it in my own websites.
However - I work on a website with a modified Twenty Thirteen.  It has a sidebar on the left.  The widget is by default located ABOVE the menu on a sidebar.  There are no options to reverse the order.

Is there a way I can make a script change which would allow me to do (permanently) this reversal?

The sidebar.php looks like that:

PRACTICE AREA 'secondary' ) ); ?>
                visit-our-blog/" >/images/visit-blog.png" alt="" />

Can anybody help me re-code it?  I would appreciate that tremendously.
Thanks,
Jack

Comment: the issue might be with the modifications. please start by posting the full code of the sidebar.

Answer (score -1):

How about using flexbox to change the order of the flex items?

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/